# Pegar valor pré definido e atribuir em outro campo

Tags: jquery

Fala galera, tenho o seguinte problema:

Preciso pegar um valor de data já definido assim 2017-06-30 (ANO-MES-DIA) e jogar ela em outro script de contagem regressiva com os seguintes parametro:

year: 2017,
month: 6,
day: 30,

Ou seja preciso pegar o ANO, MES e DIA e jogar nesses campos, acrescido de uma VIRGULA. Essa data já vem programada do término da promoção de um produto X e sempre no mesmo formato.

Comment: De onde vem a data? Veja se o comentário acima lhe ajuda - se não ajudar, por favor [inclua o seu código na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/208563/edit).

Comment: Ok, já coloquei que a data vem pré definida de outro campo e me retorna essa string como texto. 2017-06-30 e preciso dividir e joga em outro campo year: , month:, day: ,

Comment: Por favor marque a resposta como aceita, se ela resolveu o seu problema. [E faça o tour!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

De onde virá essa data? Será um formulário onde o usuário inserirá a data? Caso seja, nesse caso você nem precisa utilizar jQuery, basta inserir um campo do tipo `date` no formulário, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<form action="pagina.php" method="POST">
  <input type="date" name="data" id="data">
</form>
```

**Obs.:** Apesar de no campo a data aparecer no formato DD/MM/AAAA, quando você receber o valor inserido no campo ele virá no formato AAAA-MM-DD.
A partir daí, bastará separar os valores da data com a função do `explode` do PHP:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$partes = explode("-", $data);
//      ANO            Mês              DIA
//    $partes[0]     $partes[1]      $partes[2]
$day = $partes[2];
$month = $partes[1];
$year = $partes[0];
```

Edit:
Como você obtém essa data? Caso ela venha do banco, após armazenar em uma variável, você pode passar a mesma para o script e depois desmembrar a data da forma que precisa:

```js
var data = "<?php echo $data; ?>";
var array = data.split("-");

var day = array[2];
var month = array[1];
var year = array[0];
```

Comment: Não amigo, essa data já é obtida automaticamente (pois eu seto o término da promoção no produto cadastrado) e me retorna o valor exemplo:  2017-06-30
Ai dessa variável eu precisaria dividir e jogar nesses campos em outro script:
year: , month: , day: ,

Comment: @RafaelMeirim Editei o post, veja se isso atende ao que você precisa.

Comment: Deu certo amigo, usei assim:
<script type="text/javascript">
 var data = "2017-06-01";
    var array = data.split("-");

        $(document).ready(function(){

            --------------------------------------------------------- */
            $('#timer_with_given_timezone').syotimer({

                lang: 'por',
                year:array[0],
                month:array[1],
                day:array[2],
                hour: 00,
                minute: 00,

        });
    </script>